# Scatter chart with corresponding XY pairs

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, libreoffice-calc

I need to represent data of XY-positions of a series of objects and a test subject's estimations of the positions of those objects. I'd like to pair them in the chart so that you can easily see which estimation matches which correct position, maybe by marking each position with a filled-in shape and the estimation with just an outline of the same shape in the same colour, or something like that. Can this be done in either Libreoffice or Excel? The data is currently in X, Y, X2, Y2 columns but I can change that if necessary.

Comment: Based on the information you provided, I would try to plot the data as an XY scatter. You can plot the actual positions and the estimations as two separate series on the same chart. Once both series are plotted, you can edit the properties of each one individually to change the point style to a circle, change the point color/size, etc. I would start by plotting just the actual position data, then once you've got it looking the way you want it, right click the chart and add a new series to plot the second one.

Comment: Note, if you plot the coordinates of your shape in the X-Y scatter plot, you will not be able to fill the closed shape with a flood fill type function.  You can approximated it though with a series of closely spaced lines going from one side to the other.  Also you wont be able to plot true circle easily (if at all)  You can approximated it with multiple points on the circle.  The more points you use the smoother it will look.  Alternatively you can also try using polynomial lines to generate curves, but it may take some work to get them looking right.

Comment: I suspect you need the approach in my tutorial [Multiple Series in One Excel Chart](https://peltiertech.com/multiple-series-in-one-excel-chart/).